# html attribute of JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am adding dynamic tags based on a drop down selection; but .html adds my tags as text not real html; here is my code; am I doing something wrong:

```
$("#trigger_type").change(function() {

    var my_html = "";
    var trigger = $("#trigger_type").val();

    if (trigger == "hybrid") {
        my_html = my_html + "<div class='form-group'> < label for = 'expires_on'> Expires On </label>< input type = 'text' class = 'form-control' id = 'expires_on' placeholder = 'DD-MM-YYYY'> < input type = 'radio' name = 'expires_never' value = 'never' > Never < br >< /div>";
    }
    $("#my_div").html(my_html);

});
```

If you need more clarification please let me know!

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but you might want to initialize `my_html` outside of your `.change` script.  Then you don't have to add `my_html` to `my_html` unless you're trying to `.append` html to a certain spot

Comment: try taking whitespace out of the tags eg `< label` should be `<label`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces after your `<`s.

```
< label ...
```

should be

```
<label ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bH38G/